# Using IPsec to ensure traffic between the peers is always encrypted

Tags: security, centos, vpn, ipsec

I have implemented a IPsec connection between two pairs using openswan (opens/wan) in CentOS 6. This is running fine and i can see the traffic is encrypted. However if for whatever reason the IPsec tunnel no longer exists (maybe someone turned it off, maybe it crashed, etc), traffic will still flow between the peers as unencrypted traffic.

How can I ensure that traffic between these two peers is always sent encrypted with IPsec or no traffic between the peers is accepted.

Iptables does not seem to help, as the packets go through the iptables rules twice once encrypted and once again unencrypted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check if the connection is actually encrypted by running `tcpdump` and checking for "ESP" packets.  But there's gotta be an easier way.

Comment: You're looking for `ip xfrm poli` and configuring it to *require* encryption.